# How to set values of a column based on multiple conditions in other columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried using code from many answers for similar questions to this one, but I haven't found anything that's working for me when I am trying to set multiple conditions that decides the value of a column - I also want to do this in 3 different ways.

The data I have looks like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 1     1    1    4    1
 0     1    1    1    1
 0     0    1    1    1
```

I want to add another column dependent on if columns 1-5 have a value of >=1
to look like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 category
 1     1    1    4    1   certain
 0     1    1    1    1   probable
 0     0    1    1    1   possible
```

I have tried code such as this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',header=0)
m1 = df.col1 >= 1 & df.col2 >= 1 & df.col3 >= 1 & df.col4 >= 1 & df.col5 >= 1
m2 = df.col2 >= 1 & df.col3 >= 1 & df.col4 >= 1 & df.col5 >= 1
m3 = df.col3 >= 1 & df.col4 >= 1 & df.col5 >= 1

df['category'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['certain', 'possible', 'probable'], default='Other')
```

But this gives an error at the first line:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

From trying to understand this error, do I need to set that a value >=1 is True and anything else is False before runnning this code?

Comment: Heres a good explanation on conditional creation of new columns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing parenthesis when defining the conditions. The reason behind this is that bitwise operators have [higher precedence](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html) than comparissons. Instead use:

```
m1 = (df.col1 >= 1) & (df.col2 >= 1) & (df.col3 >= 1) & 
     (df.col4 >= 1) & (df.col5 >= 1)
m2 = (df.col2 >= 1) & (df.col3 >= 1) & (df.col4 >= 1) & (df.col5 >= 1)
m3 = (df.col3 >= 1) & (df.col4 >= 1) & (df.col5 >= 1)

df['category'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['certain', 'possible', 'probable'], 
                           default='Other')
```

Which results in the expected output:

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  category
0     1     1     1     4     1   certain
1     0     1     1     1     1  possible
2     0     0     1     1     1  probable
```

Answer (score 1):

this works

```
df['cateogry'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'Certain' if sum(x.values >= 1) >= 5  else 'Probable' if sum(x.values >= 1) >= 4 else 'Possible' , axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  cateogry
0     1     1     1     4     1   Certain
1     0     1     1     1     1  Probable
2     0     0     1     1     1  Possible
```

Comment: This works, but you would prefer a vectorized solution like `np.select`

Answer (score 0):

create a function and apply it to the dataframe.

```
def create_new_column(row):
    if row['column1'] > 1 and row['column2'] > 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda x: create_new_column(x), axis=1)
```